# LetsEncrypt Certificate not working Heroku App

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot, namecheap

I have obtained a SSL certificate from LetsEncrypt and it worked perfectly because I got the following message:

```
   Resolving trust chain... done
Adding SSL certificate to ⬢ glacial-sea-18135... done
⬢ glacial-sea-18135 now served by fukuoka-53281.herokussl.com
Certificate details:
Common Name(s): www.tamuslide.org
Expires At:     2018-10-22 07:06 UTC
Issuer:         /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
Starts At:      2018-07-24 07:06 UTC
Subject:        /CN=www.tamuslide.org
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.

=== The following common names already have domain entries
www.tamuslide.org

=== Your certificate has been added successfully.  Update your application's DNS settings as follows
Domain             Record Type  DNS Target
─────────────────  ───────────  ───────────────────────────────
www.tamuslide.org  CNAME        www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com
tamuslide.org      ALIAS/ANAME  tamuslide.org.herokudns.com
```

Now the issue happens when it said to update the DNS settings which I did do but however the my app's link with https ("https://tamuslide.org/"), the page cannot reach the server. I have looked up stuff but some people said it might 24 hours to propagate but however but it did work for others.

I am using NameCheap as my domain hoster and they don't have ALIAS/ANAME. Is there anything wrong with their DNS settings. Mine looks like this:

```
www.tamuslide.org  CNAME        www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com
tamuslide.org      CNAME  tamuslide.org.herokudns.com
```

When I type `dig +noall +answer www.tamuslide.org` innthe console I get:

```
www.tamuslide.org.  1799    IN  CNAME
www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com.
www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com. 60 IN  A   34.231.150.116
www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com. 60 IN  A   52.0.104.144
www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com. 60 IN  A   34.238.48.57
www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com. 60 IN  A   52.1.117.85
www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com. 60 IN  A   34.239.63.98
www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com. 60 IN  A   34.225.24.230
www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com. 60 IN  A   34.232.181.106
www.tamuslide.org.herokudns.com. 60 IN  A   34.224.230.241
```

Comment: what do you get for your CNAME when typing `dig +noall +answer www.tamuslide.org` in the console

Comment: I get the above thing: